# How to migrate HttpWebRequest for Multipart file to HttpClient

Tags: httprequest, .net-4.5, multipartform-data, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on an ASP.Net Core 2.0 API and one of the services I need to create is to upload files to a 3rd party site via their API. The examples for their API uses HttpWebRequest and I need to migrate this to use HttpClient.

Below is the relevant portion of their example code for a file upload.

```
        var url = "https://localhost:44636/api/uploads";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        var username = "APIUser";
        var password = "APIUserPassword";
        credentialCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        var uploadFileRequest = new UploadFileRequest();
        uploadFileRequest.environment = "DEV";
        uploadFileRequest.filename = filename;
        uploadFileRequest.multipartFile = File.ReadAllText(filepath + @"\" + filename, UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
        var boundaryText = "--ACI-XFER";
        var bodyText = new StringBuilder();
        bodyText.Append("--" + boundaryText + "\r\n");
        bodyText.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"" + "\r\n\r\n");
        bodyText.Append(uploadFileRequest.filename + "\r\n");
        bodyText.Append("--" + boundaryText + "\r\n");
        bodyText.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"environment\"" + "\r\n\r\n");
        bodyText.Append(uploadFileRequest.environment + "\r\n");
        bodyText.Append("--" + boundaryText + "\r\n");
        bodyText.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"multipartFile\"; filename=\"" +
        uploadFileRequest.filename + "\"" + "\r\n");
        bodyText.Append("Content-Type: text/plain" + "\r\n\r\n");
        bodyText.Append(uploadFileRequest.multipartFile + "\r\n");
        bodyText.Append("--" + boundaryText + "--");
        var bodyBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyText.ToString());
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryText;
        request.ContentLength = bodyBytes.Length;
        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var responseText = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
                    {
                        logger.Debug("HttpWebResponse: \r\n" + responseText + "\r\n");
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (logger.IsErrorEnabled)
                {
                    logger.Error("HttpWebResponse Error UploadProcessFile(), Server: " +
                   webResponse.Server + ", StatusCode: " + webResponse.StatusCode + ", StatusDescription: " +
                   webResponse.StatusDescription);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 using the HttpClient, I have come up with this code, but when I try to upload the file, I get a 400 error stating "Please select a file to upload"

```
            boundryText = "ACI-XFER"
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44636");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                string relativeUrl = "api/uploads";
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, relativeUrl);
                var byteArray = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("APIUser:APIUserPassword");
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundryText))
                {
                    content.Add(new StringContent(uploadFileRequestDto.FileName + "\r\n"), "filename");
                    content.Add(new StringContent(uploadFileRequestDto.PdxEnvironment + "\r\n"), "environment");
                    Encoding encNoBoM = new UTF8Encoding(false);
                    content.Add(new StringContent(uploadFileRequestDto.TextFile + "\"" + "\r\n", encNoBoM, "text/plain"), "multipartfile", uploadFileRequestDto.FileName);
                    request.Content = content;
                    response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                }

            }

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                uploadFileResponseDto = (uploadFileResponseDto)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);
                uploadFileResponseDto.Success = true;
                uploadFileResponseDto.StatusCode = 200;
                return uploadFileResponseDto;
            }

            _logger.LogError("File upload for Id [{ID}] failed. Reason: {ReasonPhrase}", uploadFileRequestDto.Id, response.ReasonPhrase);
            uploadFileResponseDto.Success = false;
            uploadFileResponseDto.Reason = string.Format($"Status Code: [{response.StatusCode}], Reason: [{response.ReasonPhrase}]");
            uploadFileResponseDto.StatusCode = 500;
            return uploadFileResponseDto;
```

Here is the request as it looks in Fiddler;

```
    **Headers**

    POST /api/uploads HTTP/1.1
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="--ACI-XFER"
    Accept: application/json
    Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    x-ms-request-root-id: 4f112b3-4c33c20cb1d76dec
    x-ms-request-id: |4f112b3-4c33c20cb1d76dec.1.
    Request-Id: |4f112b3-4c33c20cb1d76dec.1.1.
    Content-Length: 325354
    Host: localhost:44636


    Content

    ----ACI-XFER
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name=filename

    test1upload.txt
    ----ACI-XFER
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name=environment

    DEV
    ----ACI-XFER
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name=multipartfile; filename=test1upload.txt; filename*=utf-8''test1upload.txt

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
```

I feel that the problem is coming from how I am doing this line in my code, which sets up the text file content to upload;

```
content.Add(new StringContent(uploadFileRequestDto.TextFile + "\"" + "\r\n", encNoBoM, "text/plain"), "multipartfile", uploadFileRequestDto.FileName);
```

I had first tried it like this, without the added and slashes and carriage return line feed, but got the same error.

```
content.Add(new StringContent(uploadFileRequestDto.TextFile, encNoBoM, "text/plain"), "multipartfile", uploadFileRequestDto.FileName);
```

But I am having difficulty finding a good example of how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you link to some relevant documentation for the 3rd party API?

Comment: As it turns out, the only problem was that I was using "multipartform" (all lower case) in my implementation when it should have been "multipartForm". Changing my implementation to use the string "multipartForm" solved the problem and everything now is working fine.